# Can you get a closed-form for $\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, closed-form, infinite-product

When I use the **Taylor expansion series** for $$\log(1+x)^{1+x}+\log(1-x)^{1-x}$$ with $x=\frac{1}{p}$, $p$ **prime**, I believe that I can deduce 
$$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\left(\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3p^4}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5p^6}+\frac{1}{4\cdot7p^8}+\cdots\right)=\log\frac{6}{\pi^2}+\log\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

If previous computations are right, and can be justified I want to ask the following

> **Question.** Can you compute 
>   $$\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}?$$

**Thanks in advance.**

My goal is learn, thus if you can give the details about how are justified the more important steps to deduce my computations it is the best. Also, how can we justify the convergence of such infinite product?

Comment: Is that $\log((1+x)^{1+x})$ or is it $(\log(1+x))^{1+x}$? (The same question for the $1-x$ part.)

Comment: I hope that there aren't mistakes, is $\log((1+x)^{1+x})$, the same answer for the $1-x$ part Thanks @BenS.

Comment: That does not look like a product we can evaluate in closed form. However finding a good approximation for the product is much easier (which btw evaluates to $\simeq 2.622399$).

Comment: Very thanks much @Winther I've tried to use an online calculator, and I don't obtain any approximation. I accept your words about does not look like we can evaluate in closed form, but when I did my question I don't know if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Don't take my word for it, it's just a hunch. Generally speaking if there is no obvious reason for why there should be a closed form (like here) there usually is not a closed form. btw to derive the number i quoted above I used that $(1\pm \frac{1}{p})^{\frac{1}{p}} \approx 1 \pm \frac{1}{p^2}$ when $p$ is large. The products $\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1\pm \frac{1}{p_n^2}$ can be evaluated in closed form. By explicitly evaluating the first $N$ terms of the product and using the approximation for the rest of the terms we can get a pretty good approximation. I used $N=1000$ for the number above..

Comment: @user243301 : $P(s) = \sum_p p^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) \frac{\ln \zeta(n s)}{n}$ which is the [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) of $\ln \zeta(s) = \sum_{p} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\textstyle r p^{sr}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{P(sk)}{k}$

Comment: You are welcome, always I take notes from your contribution, now I think about this, if I can deduce it, Very thanks much @user1952009

Comment: To give meaning for all comments, too I ask in comments if someone know if previous infnite product is trancendental or irrational. I delete some comment for clarity. Thanks all users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prime products that are 'easy' to evaluate are usually those that can somehow be related somehow to the [Euler product for the Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula)

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_p \left[1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right]\tag{1}$$

Your product is not on this form, or anything resembling it, so that makes evaluating it much harder so I doubt that there is a known closed form for it. Note for example that there [is not even](http://oeis.org/A065474) a known closed form for the much simpler product $\prod_p\left[1- \frac{2}{p^2}\right]$. However we can derive a very good approximation for your product.

For $x\ll 1$ we have the approximation $(1+x)^m \approx 1+mx$. By taking $m = x = \frac{1}{p}$ we obtain

$$\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{p}}{1-\frac{1}{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\approx \frac{1+\frac{1}{p^2}}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}~~~~\text{for large }p$$

The product of the term above can be evaluated since $\prod_{p} \left[1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right] = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and $\prod_{p} \left[1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right] = \frac{15}{\pi^2}$. These products can be derived from the Euler product $(1)$ as $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$ and $\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}$ respectively. Now by multiplying togeather the first $N$ terms in your product and using the approximation above for the remaining terms we obtain the simple approximation

$$\prod_p \left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \approx \frac{5}{2}\prod_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{p_n+1}{p_n-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_n}}\frac{p_n^2-1}{p_n^2+1}$$

which gets better and better the larger we take $N$. For example if $N=3$ we get $\frac{72}{65} 2^{2/15} 3^{7/10}\simeq 2.62145$ which are within $0.04\%$ of the true answer $2.62239915779\ldots$ found by numerically evaluating the sum for $N=10000$.

Comment: Very thanks much, I take notes from your answer, and I am trying understand all.